# How to deploy the vue-cli project to product enviroment?

Tags: node.js, deployment, vue-cli

Recently I begin to use vue-cli to generate a pure front-end project(not use npm express anymore).
When I on the develop phase everything is fine.Cause I can use the magic.

```
npm run dev
```

And then I want to run the project on the production environment,but I'm not sure this way is a good idea.

So I google some method to teach me how to deploy the vue-cli project,but I only got

run

```
npm run build
```

After that I got a dist folder,and what is the next step?

is there a way like run the node express project ?

```
node ./bin/www
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer,and don't need the hosting. Here we go.

Step 1 : Build the project and get the dist directory.

Step 2 : Let the nginx reference to this dist directory.(Just treat it like static files)

Step 3 : You can use browser to browse your website now.